# passing jquery variable to php function as parameter

Tags: php, jquery

```
$("#slider-range-max-day-count").slider({
                range: "max",
                min: 1,
                max: 365,
                value: 1,
                animate: "fast",
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#dayCount").text(ui.value);
                    var invPackageValue = $('#investmentPackage').text();
                    var dayValue = ui.value;
                    <?php
                    $compoundInterest = $CI->compound_int($package, $day, $interest_rate->static_interest);
                    ?>
                    $("#sliderResult").text(<?php echo $compoundInterest;?>);
                }
            });
```

In the function `$CI->compound_int($package, $day, $interest_rate->static_interest);` how to pass invPackageValue and dayValue instead of `$package` and `$day` parameter.

Comment: This is a php file?

Comment: yes, this is php file

Comment: You should use ajax for passing jquery vaiables to PHP and then you can pass it as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ajax call to use javascript variable in php. Pass javascript variable in request of the ajax call. Then we can get values in php file of those variable and execute the function in php file and return the output and in ajax success function we can get the response.

//Javascript + Jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#slider-range-max-day-count").slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 1,
        max: 365,
        value: 1,
        animate: "fast",
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#dayCount").text(ui.value);
            var invPackageValue = $('#investmentPackage').text();
            var dayValue = ui.value;
            $.ajax({
                url : 'PATH OF SAME FILE',
                data : 'package='+invPackageValue+'&day='+dayValue,
                type : 'post',
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data){
                    $("#sliderResult").text(data.compoundInterest);
                }
            });         
        }
    });
</script>
```

//PHP CODE

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['package'])){
        $compoundInterest = $CI->compound_int($package, $day, $interest_rate->static_interest);
        echo json_encode(['compoundInterest'=>$compoundInterest]);exit;
    }
?>
```